# Convention: Storing Python function output in constant?

Tags: python, pep8

I am aware that constants in Python are more of a convention yet I got into an argument with a fellow programmer over the following line:

```
FILE = open("file.txt").readlines()
```

With `FILE` later used multiple times, e.g. in a `for line in FILE`

We want to code as good as possible. I believe `FILE` should *never* be declared as a constant because it relies on the output of the `open()` and `readlines()` functions. Yet the counter-argument is that `FILE` never changes in our program, so behaves like a constant should. Which one is it?

Exceptions aside, shouldn't it be a variable, i.e. written as a variable according to the naming conventions, so `file` in all lowercase?

Comment: Python doesn't have constants.  What case you use to name your variables is of absolutely no relevance to the interpreter.

Comment: @jwodder He's clearly referring to the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) guideline about constants. I added the relevant tag.

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't be a constant. Some well accepted constants would be `XXX = "foo"+"bar"`. That's also computed but clearly a constant. The slight difference here is that the list is mutable. The string isn't (but reference could be clobbered as well)

Comment: unrelated: `file` is an appropriate name for the result of `open()` function. An appropriate name for `.readlines()`' return value is `lines`. A better name depends on what `file.txt` actually stores. 2- Specify in the question whether `file.txt` may change *ever* while the script is running.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian in this case, `file.txt` does not change while it's running; but what if it did? and furthermore, what if you didn't know? it seems like `file` is always the better choice than `FILE`

Comment: @Dimebag as I said: neither `FILE` nor `file` should be used here. Whether to use LINES or lines might depend. Other parts of your program do not care how you've got the constant value but you shouldn't use LINES if the value may ever change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant is not just something that doesn't change over the life of a program run, it's a name for something whose value is predefined, and generally independent of the dynamic state of the application or environment.  Typical uses are for things like mathematical constants like `PI`, or application parameters like `NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS`.

In your example, the value of `FILE` is dependent on the contents of the file. It's not a predefined constant, since the file can change from one run of the program to the next.

Another way to look at it is that when you see a use of a constant in the program, you just have to find the initialization of it to know what its value is. But if you initialize the constant from a file, you can't tell what its value will be.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) doesn't define "constant", so you can do whatever you like, but I think most programmers would find your intended use of `FILE` to be confusing or non-idiomatic. Consider that in some programming languages, what you're attempting would not even be possible -- if they have explicit `constant` declarations, they require that the value be calculable at compile time.

Comment: what if the function is a pure function? e.g., compute π to 1000 digits.

Comment: I'd run it once and then copy the result into a literal in the program. :)

Comment: It both hurts readability and makes changes unnecessarily harder.

Comment: Anyway, that's a borderline case that doesn't fit neatly into either category, you can do what you like. In a language with compile-time constants (e.g. C++), that would have to be a variable, so I think that becomes a good model for how to do it in languages where constants are just a naming convention.

Comment: I don't think mentioning c++ simplifies things but you could use `constexpr` for a pure function there. I can imagine `X, Y, Z, W = range(4)` code as (Go's iota analog).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But it's harder to imagine a `constexpr` function that calculates the digits of pi. Theoretically possible, since it's a pure function, but I'm not sure any real compiler could pull it off (although you could obviously do it in Common Lisp, where the macro preprocessor is the full language).